Firebase : Error when deploying a project
I use Firebase for my project. I have used Firebase hosting for couple of times and never had a problem. I am trying to deploy a project created by Next.js ver 14.2.3 but Firebase is telling me:

Error: Your project  must be on the Blaze (pay-as-you-go) plan to complete this command. Required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com can't be enabled until the upgrade is complete. To upgrade, visit the following URL:

I have dynamic pages and authentication on my app, can I not deploy it on Firebase? I followed the items on this link in order to deploy my app:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/nextjs
NOTE: Even though it says "The latest supported Next.js version is 13.4.7.", I saw some apps deployed to Firebase hosting with the version of 14.


I have dynamic pages and authentication on my app, can I not deploy it on Firebase?

You can deploy it, but only if your project is on a payment plan.  That's what the error message is trying to tell you.  Dynamic pages are served with Cloud Functions, which requires that you have a credit card for any billing that it might incur past the free limit.  I suggest reviewing the Firebase pricing documentation for more information.  See also the first step of Firebase App Hosting documentation (emphasis mine):

If you don't already have one, create a Firebase project and make sure it has the Blaze pricing plan enabled.


I thought so, just wanted to try my chance if I could handle this for free. Thank you for answering.
